# run command on device when adb killed

Tags: android, shell, process, adb, signals

I need to run some code on android device via `adb exec-out`, but it requires an important cleanup code to be executed also on the device whenever main code finishes (including disconnedted USB, killed adb, etc.).

My idea was push and run something like:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
cleanup() {
  trap - INT TERM HUP PIPE EXIT
  echo "We need to run this!" >> /sdcard/cleanup.log
}
trap cleanup INT TERM HUP PIPE EXIT
echo "Some long running fancy stuff"
sleep 60
```

When I push it and run it via interactive shell then it works fine.
On <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd> it calls the `cleanup()`, but when I run it from the host
`adb shell /path/to/script` then whatever signal I send to the host adb then the device `cleanup()` is never called.

I was expectig adbd to send SIGHUP to whole process group on the device in case of adb connection drop.

The only solution I can think of at the moment is to start separatce anti-watchdog kind of process that will keep pooling processes and run the cleanup if not found, but this is so ugly that I deciced to ask you guys for some advice.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented watching/cleanup process on device side without pooling:

```sh
WATCH=/data/local/tmp/watch

# Start the watching process on device
adb shell <<EOF!
    mkfifo "${WATCH}"
    (
        exec </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1
        # Magic here: this will block until main process finishes
        cat "${WATCH}" > /dev/null
        echo "Critical cleanup goes here..."
    ) &
EOF!

# Start the main process and let WATCH-er know if killed
adb exec-out "producer-on-device | tee ${WATCH}" | consumer-on-host
```

So it's not that ugly after all and works well even if I disconnect the USB or [kill dash nine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hk9NxydtPOU) the adb. It was fun.